# Commutator Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula

Tags: lie-algebras, power-series, noncommutative-algebra

Consider the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula $\Phi(X,Y)\in\mathbb{Q}\langle\!\langle X,Y\rangle\!\rangle$ in non-commutative variables. Define $X*Y:=\Phi(X,Y)$ and $[X,Y]=(-X)*(-Y)*X*Y$, and then (as usual) define for any vector
$\mathbf{e}=(e_1,\ldots,e_r)\in\mathbb{N}^r$ the repeated commutator

$$[X,Y]_{\mathbf{e}}:=[X,\underbrace{Y,\ldots,Y}_{e_1},\underbrace{X,\ldots,X}_{e_2},\ldots]$$
 (here $[X_1,\ldots,X_r]$ is defined as $[[X_1,\ldots,X_{r-1}],X_r]$).

I think that there is an analogous of the BCH formula which $XY-YX$ in terms of the commutators $[X,Y]_\mathbf{e}$. That is, if for $\mathbf{e}=(e_1,\ldots,e_r)$ we define $\langle\mathbf{e}\rangle=e_1+\ldots+e_r$ then there exist rational numbers $t_\mathbf{e}$ for all $\mathbf{e}\in\mathbb{N}^r$ and for all $r$ such that if we put $v_n(X,Y)=\sum_{<\mathbf{e}>=n}t_\mathbf{e}[X,Y]_\mathbf{e}$
then

$$XY-YX=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}v_n(X,Y)$$.

I would appreciate any reference about this.

Comment: Use `\langle x\rangle` instead of `<x>` to obtain $\langle x\rangle$ instead of $<x>$. The spacing of `<` is quite different because it is interpreted as a relation.

Comment: 1. Just to make sure: you mean that you define $[X,Y]$ as $\log(e^{-X}e^{-Y}e^Xe^Y)$, right? That $(-X)*(-Y)*X*Y$, though formally the same (?), keeps confusing me. 
2. Can you prove your formula, or you expect it to be true? If the latter, did you check it up to some reasonable order, or it's just a feeling?

Comment: (Similarly, you can write `\mathbb Q\rangle\!\rangle X,Y\langle\!\langle` which gives $\mathbb Q\rangle\!\rangle X,Y\langle\!\langle$; `\newcommand` is your friend :) ) 

Comment: To add to Vladimir Dotsenko's comment, do I understand correctly that on the left hand side of your displayed equation, $[X,Y]$ means $\log(e^{-X} e^{-Y} e^X e^Y)$ but, on the right hand side, it is the standard commutator $XY-YX$?

Comment: Yes, I used this notation because when we work in a nilpotent Lie algebra then $*$ will be the group operation which makes into a group. This question follows from Corollary 3, Chap 6, of Segal's book: Polycyclic groups, where it is proved that if $x_1,\ldots,x_s\in Tr_1(n,k)$ then $(\log x_1,\ldots,\log x_s)=\log [x_1,\ldots,x_s]+\sum_i s_i \log v_i$ where each $v_i$ is repeated group commutator of length at least $s+1$ in $x_1,\ldots,x_s$ and each $s_i$ is a universal constant dependeing only on $n$ (here $Tr_1(n,k)$ is the unipotent group of upper triangular matrices with 1s in the diagonal

Comment: Yes, $[X,Y]$ means $\log(e^{-X}e^{-Y}e^Xe^Y)$ and $XY-YX$ is the standard commutator in non-commutative variables.

Comment: @Diego, you could adopt the angle bracket suggestions of Mariano.

Comment: Have you checked Chapter 6 of the book "Analytic pro-$p$ groups" by Dixon, du Sautoy, Mann and Segal? 



Comment: Yes, I checked that book and it says that there is an analogous BCH formula for $\log(\exp(-x)\exp(-y)\exp(x)\exp(y))$, that is, it can be expressed as a series in terms of repetead Lie brakets (for Lie brakets I mean (X,Y)=XY-YX ) as in the BCH formula for $\Phi(X,Y)$. Now I realize that combining this with the idea on how Corollary 3 can be obtained from Corollary 2 in Chapter 6 of Segal's book, Polycyclic group, I could get a confirmation of this fact.